# Django static files for dashboard not loading

Tags: python, django, pycharm

Hi I am fairly new to django and I am trying to learn adding dashboard to django using this tutorial - [Django Plotly Dash Tutorial on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=psvU4zwO3Ao&t=339s&ab_channel=PipInstallPython). I was able to load all the html files, unfortunately I am unsuccessful with the static files.

This is my project file directories

[image]

My Project Settings.py

```
STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'static'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'sample2/static')
]
```

Some base.html code

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<!-- Meta, title, CSS, favicons, etc. -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="icon" href="../images/favicon.ico" type="image/ico" />

<title>This </title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="{% static '../vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link href="{% static '../vendors/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css'%}" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- NProgress -->
<link href="{% static '../vendors/nprogress/nprogress.css'%}" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- iCheck -->
<link href="{% static '../vendors/iCheck/skins/flat/green.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

MY welcome.html under home app

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}
{% load static %}
```

The only things that I didn't follow on the tutorial was not install a database and not declare the `{%load staticfiles%}` because I have read that Django 3.1.3 has depreciated this command.

What am I missing here? Thank you.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

Comment: Hi, check this post, you have several problems in your template when you refer css files similar to the question of this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65024422/css-bootstrap-and-javascript-is-not-working-with-django/65024588#65024588

Comment: are you sure added INSTALLED_APPS = [ ---,home
 ]

Comment: Hi! This is what I add based on the turorial  'home.apps.HomeConfig',

Answer (score 1):

In my setting.py file, `BASE_DIR` indicate to `/Users/username/userfolder/django-project`.

I'm guessing if your `BASE_DIR` is indicated to `/Users/username/userfolder/sample2`, then the path will be duplicate **sample2** in your `STATICFILES_DIRS` due to the code below:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'sample2/static') ]
```

Suppose `BASE_DIR` points to your project dir, the right path for `STATICFILES_DIRS` should be `os.path.join(BASE_DIR / "static")`

Also you could print out those values to check on console.

For more info: [Managing static files (e.g. images, JavaScript, CSS)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/)

Answer (score 1):

```
app = DjangoDash('Home',add_bootstrap_links=True)`

app.css.append_css({ "external_url" : "/static/assets/style.css" })
```

place your assets folder in Django static folder

If you get Python Error: No module named bootstrap4.bootstrap try

```
pip install "django_bootstrap4==1.1.1"
```

or

```
pip install django_bootstrap4
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Got the Static file working thanks to **ha-neul**.

What I did was change all the link url from `'../vendors/xxx/xxxx' to '/vendors/xxx/xxx'`

As for the images, I added the command `MEDIA_URL = '/static/'`

Now everything is working. Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

Have you added the static directories to your urls.py?

It should look like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```